# PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is ignored

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, with the package php7.0-sybase (version 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) installed. Version of FreeTDS is 0.91 (the latest currently available on Ubuntu)

this is the content of my `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

```
[global]
        text size = 64512
[mssql]
        host = 192.0.1.5
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

this is the content of my `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[mssql]
Description    = MSSQL Server
Driver         = freetds
Database       = MY_DB
ServerName     = MSSQL
TDS_Version    = 8.0
```

the following is the php script I'm trying

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('dblib:host=192.0.1.5;port=1433;dbname=MY_DB;charset=UTF-8', 'my_user', 'my_pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, true);

$sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 my_field FROM dbo.my_table';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($all = $stmt->fetchAll());
```

I expect to see the content of field as a guid, instead I'm getting the binary content

For example, I expect to see `[my_field] => 8CAFC97B-30C2-4096-9367-9D240085A16E` and instead I get `[my_field] => {ɯ▒▒0▒@▒g▒$▒▒n`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your database is storing the GUIDs as binary, for performance purpose. You will need to transform binary ({ɯ▒▒0▒@▒g▒$▒▒n) to hexadecimal (8CAFC97B-30C2-4096-9367-9D240085A16E) with a PHP or SQL function. I'm developing a system that uses GUIDs as binary on a MySQL database. Here is a the code I'm using to convert from hex to binary, to insert on the DB, and from binary to hex to get a human readable content:

From binary to hexadecimal:

```
public static function getId($string)
{
    return strtoupper(preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]{12})/', '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5', bin2hex($string)));
}
```

From hexadecimal do binary:

```
public static function generateId($string)
{
    return hex2bin(str_replace('-', '', $string));
}
```

Remembering that you need to remove the GUID's dashes to be able to convert to binary.

These functions are in a Helper class inside my system. So whenever I need them, I just call the Helper. You can also make it available all through the application if it's better for you.